# Can somebody sign into my account even if I have it as primary

Tags: ps4

I recently gameshared with a friend and I no longer want him using my account anymore, so I told him de-activate the account as primary and I activated it as primary instead. He probably still has it as a user on his playstation and I would like to know if he can just select my account to get in and activate it as primary again.
 Will he be able to make any purchases?

Comment: Why don't you just change your password? That should log the user out from your friend's console.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, you should change the password immediately.

Non-Primary accounts are able to spend funds in your wallet.
Also be aware that there is a limit of sign-ins per account, to play games or watch videos.

https://www.playstation.com/en-nz/get-help/help-library/my-account/device-activation-deactivation/about-device-deactivation/